# Increasable and decreasable signal strengths

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to be able to press a button to increase a signal's strength by 1 and press another button to decrease it by 1. I have thought about making 15 t flip-flops, but that sounds like a difficult way of doing it. What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is probably the most compact circuit of this type; it additionally can accept pulses on any length on both inputs and provides symmetrical signals, x and 15-x on the two sides. The only downside is that you need 18 stacks of any 64-stackable item, to completely fill the droppers under the repeaters - the other droppers are to be left empty. Both repeaters should be set to 2 ticks.

This circuit should also work on Bedrock Edition, with the small modification - add solid blocks on top of the empty droppers to power them through these blocks - on JE they can be powered through quasi-connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a viable solution:
[Signal strength memory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etVGAF2p7zk)

It does exactly what the description says, except the "button" has to be exactly 2 ticks or it will increase/decrease too much. A simple pulse shortener should sort that out.

Here is what it looks like as well as a layer breakdown:

[image: Final + Breakdown]

Comment: Pleas do not post link-only answers as the links may become unreachable or unavailable. You can put the link as your source but you must include some basic description of the links.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have two droppers facing each other and get a signal from one with a comparator, one button could cause a dropper to add a item to the other and increase the signal strength and the other dropper could send an item back to the other to decrease signal strength.